# Regarding PHP comment box

Tags: php, html, jquery, facebook

I'm a beginner at PHP. Currently I am developing a Facebook comment box on my site. I created a comment box successfully, and if I login in this sense it will go through `facebook.com.login.php` , but I need that login go through my web site page instance of facebook.com. Is there any code for it?

Can anyone can tell me the answer please. I'm little confuse about it...

Comment: we're also confused about what you're trying to accomplish. clear your thoughts and rephrase.

Comment: if your working any one of that site inthis sense you will login to face book.. if you click that login button that will go to faceboo.com..this is example site http://twitter.com/exclusivetaxi/.. thanks gowtham

Comment: @fattick stop creating new versions of your same question.  I've merged them here; if you need to update this question, then you can edit it by clicking the **| edit |** link at the bottom of your question.  And, if your question gets closed, consider the answer to be "no, you cannot do this."

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using the Facebook code generator to give you your comment box? http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments.

This should generate all the code you need and use a pop up box for logging in to Facebook.

Answer (score 0):

fb:comments should allow anonymous comments. You need to initialize the [Javascript SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) before using it.

Read more here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments

```
<div id="fb-root"></div><script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=APP_ID&amp;xfbml=1"></script><fb:comments numposts="10" width="425" publish_feed="true"></fb:comments>
```

Hope it helps